# How to host staging and production on the same server

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, nginx, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to server administration and I've recently setup my rails app on a Linode server. I followed a similar configuration to the [Ryan Bates railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=asciicast) on the subject. With nginx, unicorn and Ubuntu 14.04.2.

This works great with the one app. But I'd like to setup a staging site on the same server. It is only a small app that uses little resources and this should keep costs low.

How do I go about this? I have already configured and uploaded two apps to my root directory (application and staging). But I only have one IP address. How do I configure one DNS record to application and the other to staging? I don't even know which IP address to use to access my staging server in the browser. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to how you go about this is: you don't.

If any problem you can forseeably cause in the staging environment can also have an impact on the production environment, it's not really a staging environment. You're doing your testing in production.

- If you fill the disk, you've impacted production.
- If you peg the CPU, you've impacted production.
- If you devour all available memory, you've impacted production.
- If you saturate the NIC (virtual or physical), you've impacted production.

If you insist on using a single server for both environments, this probably isn't the right SE site to ask your question on. (due to our focus on business IT needs, i.e. uptime)